# Add a dummy entry to DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I have the following razor syntax for creating a dropdown list from a list of objects.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.data_connection, 
        new SelectList( Model.connections, 
          "ID", "Title", 
           Model.data_connection) , 
        new { style = "width: 420px;" })
```

This works, but I'd like to add a `- select a connection -` style dummy entry to the top of the list. I can do this by passing a `SelectList` instead of my collection of objects, but I'm wondering if there's a nice easy way to do this in the view?

Comment: you mean a placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229626/dropdownlistfor-default-value)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.data_connection, 
    new SelectList( Model.connections, 
      "ID", "Title", 
       Model.data_connection) , 
    " -- select a connection -- ",
    new { style = "width: 420px;" })
```