# Model Validation not working with all properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have the following ViewModel:

```
 public class MyViewModel:IValidatableObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please fill the name", new string[] { "Name" });

            if (Birthday.HasValue == false)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please fill the birthday", new string[] { "Birthday" });

            if(Status <= 0)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please fill the status", new string[] { "Status" });
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Birthday,Status")] MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MyViewModels.Add(myViewModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

I would like to display all the validation messages at the same time, however it shows first status and then the other two properties.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the order in which validation happens. First the ModelBinder does it's job, and if that passes, since you've created a self validating viewmodel by implementing `IValidatableObject`, the `Validate` method is called. In the first screenshot the modelbinding process is failing so Validate is never called. In the second screenshot, modelbinding succeeds, but `Validate()` fails.

You can solve this by using DataAnnotations instead of implementing `IValidatableObject` like so:

```
    public class MyViewModel:IValidatableObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        [Required, Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result keeping IValidatableObject?

Comment: If you did all your validation through the Validate() method, yes. Just make all the properties on the viewmodel optional and write your rules in Validate().

Comment: changing to public int? Status { get; set; } It displays only Name and Birthday validation messages.

Ps: All my validation is done using Valida from IValidatableObject

Comment: Right, but at that point you'd need to check Status.HasValue and manually add validation errors yourself just as you're currently doing for the Birthday property.

Comment: it's almost working. My only problem is when I change to Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Status) for example. It still validating Status first

Comment: Maybe set a default value of -1 for your dropdownlist, something similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229626/dropdownlistfor-default-value