# Adding empty value to a DropDownListFor using select2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-select2

I want to add an empty value explicitly so that I can use that with jQuery.

```
$('#empId').select2({
    placeholder: "Select report type",
    allowClear: true,
    width: "265px"
});
```

How can I make it appear as the first (empty) option of the select?

Code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpNameSelected,
    new SelectList(Model.ListOfEmployee, "", "", Model.EmpNameSelected),
     Model.EmpNameSelected, new { id = "empId" })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropdownListFor default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229626/dropdownlistfor-default-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this model:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string EmpNameSelected { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> ListOfEmployee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult TestEmployeeDropDownList()
    {
        var model = new EmployeeModel
        {
            ListOfEmployee = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeName = "John Doe" },
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 2, EmployeeName = "John Roe" },
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 3, EmployeeName = "Jane Doe" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Finally the View:

```
@{
    var emptyEmployee = new MvcApplication.Models.Employee { EmployeeId = 0, EmployeeName = string.Empty };
    Model.ListOfEmployee.Insert(0, emptyEmployee);
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpNameSelected, new SelectList(Model.ListOfEmployee, "EmployeeId", "EmployeeName", 0), new { id = "empId" })
```

Comment: is there a no way to do using the razor? i really do not want to mess up adding in my controller and i was thinking that it can be achieved using the overrides

Comment: @AbuHamzah which is the part that you want to replace with razor?

Comment: adding empty values like `new {value = "", text = ""},` on the razor code

Comment: @AbuHamzah I understood what you mean, please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks let me take a look

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help others...

What I really needed is just one line of code to insert a new `empty value`

```
@{Model.ListOfEmployee.Insert(0, "");}  //insert empty value

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpNameSelected,
    new SelectList(Model.ListOfEmployee, "", "", Model.EmpNameSelected),
     Model.EmpNameSelected, new { id = "empId" })
```