# How to set default value in dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I have a gender enum like this:
my enumlist.cs

```
 public enum Gender
{
    [Description("male")]
    male= 0,
    [Description("female")]
    female= 1,
   
}
```

But when it is displayed in View, I need DropDown to display ---Please Select --- as default value. So that i can check required validation in jQuery Script.

cteate.html ,

```
   <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12 form-title">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender) 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-8 col-12 form-data">
                          

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SubMIS.Models.Gender))), "---Please Select ---", new { @class = "rwd-select" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
                        <label style="color: red">@ViewBag.GenderError</label>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How to do this? what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DropdownListFor default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229626/dropdownlistfor-default-value)

Comment: If Md Farid Uddin Kiron's answer solved you problem, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying value from `Enum` in `asp.net` has built
in helper class `asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<YourEnumName>`. However, in your code you are doing otherwise so that you couldn't set a value in that format as setting value using `DropDownListFor` is not supported. Let's move to the solution.

**Enum:**

```
public enum Gender
    {
        [Description("male")]
        male = 0,
        [Description("female")]
        female = 1,
        
    }
```

**View:**

```
 @using DotNetMVCWebApp.Enums
 <select asp-for="Gender" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>()">
   <option selected="selected" value="1">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Note: I have modified the `Enum` value as `[Description("male")] male = 2, [Description("female")] female = 3,` so that I could set `default value as 1` as you can see the default value below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Work Around To Handle Easily**

**Modify The Enum:**

```
public enum Gender
    {
        [Display(Name = "Please Select")] Select = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Male")] Male = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Female")] Female = 2,
       
    }
```

Note: If you can see here I am setting the the `default enum` as `Please Select` so that it will be `assigned value` on `DropDownListFor` and you do not need to do anything else.

**View:**

```cs
@using DotNet6MVCWebApp.Enums
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), new { @class = "rwd-select" })
```

**Note:** Here point to remember just remove `"---Please Select ---"` from your `@Html.DropDownListFor` as this will come from the `Enum`. And only this will required least modification what you are trying to implement.

**But I prefer Like below:**

```cs
@using DotNet6MVCWebApp.Enums
@Html.DropDownList("Gender", Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>(),  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Output:**

[image]